# Protecting multiple API's

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Imagine a situation where we have one IdentityServer, one MVC client and 2 API's. So there are 2 API Resources (`Api1` and `Api2`). `Api2` is a complete copy of `Api1` but with some customization. Now the administrator user should be authorized to access both API's but another user would only be allowed acces to `Api2`.

Would it make sense to add a claim to a user `Api1.Access` and `Api2.Access` and set this up as an authorization policy  in the corresponding API. Does identity server provide something for this like add an API resource based on a user?

Comment: cant you just define different scopes?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by defining different scopes.
Scopes are changed to APIResources. A client has an APIResource, not a user. What would this mean?

Comment: As you have `Roles` claim already, aint it possible to handle use that and handle this in the api itself with Authorization attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claims are about identity - not permissions.

You need to check if the user is allowed to access the API from within the API.

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/